# Find the chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

So I need to find I believe the chromatic polynomial of the below graph so that I find out the number of ways to colour the vertices with 3 and 4 colours.

[image: graph to be coloured]

From my general understanding I began by labeling the vertices with possibilities:

$ x = $ total number of colours

$ f = x $

$ c, b = x-1 $

$ a, d = x-3 $

$ e, g = x-2 $

Thus I get

$ x(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)^2 $

But really not sure if this is right at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not quite right. This approach will only work for graphs with a very special structure, which this one doesn't have. In this case the problem is when you choose colours for $a$ and $d$, the number of choices you have will depend on whether you coloured $b$ and $c$ differently to each other (in which case you do have $x-3$ choices for $a$) or the same (in which case you have $x-2$ choices, since there are only two colours you've used so far).

This is actually enough to do your graph by splitting into two cases: work out the number of colourings where $b,c$ are the same, and the number where they are different, and add them together. In general this gives the deletion-contraction formula which leads to a recursive algorithm for finding the chromatic polynomial.

Comment: Okay. So I now have $x((x-1)^2(x-2)^2 + (x-1)^2(x-3)^2)((x-2)^2+(x-3)^2)$ in an attempt to plus together the different possibilities as you have described. I don't feel confident in this answer though, please advise?

Comment: No, that doesn't look right to me. You should just be adding two terms. If $b$ and $c$ are the same colour there are $x$ ways to choose $f$, $x-1$ to choose $b$, $1$ way to choose $c$ (the same as $b$) and $x-2$ each for the other four vertices, so you get $x(x-1)(x-2)^4$. If they are different then there are $x$ choices for $f$, $x-1$ for $b$, $x-2$ for $c$ (since it's different from $b$), and then $x-3$ ways for each of $a$ and $d$ and $x-2$ each for the other two, giving $x(x-1)(x-2)^3(x-3)^2$.

Comment: I see. So then I add it like: $x(x-1)(x-2)^4 + x(x-1)(x-2)^3(x-3)^2$ ?

Comment: Following which I think I would have $x(x-1)(x-2)^3(x^2-5x+7)$

Comment: Yes, that's what I get.